# How to put 2 text input fields in one?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have see some cool effects that put two text input fields in one as a form! I have attached an image for you to see so you know what I mean. Does anyone know how to create such a thing?

Can it be done with CSS?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to a website that does this?

Comment: This is just two input boxes with their styling removed, wrapped in an element with some styling added. No big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can style it up like so - http://jsbin.com/adalot/1/

This should set you off in the right direction

```
  <div id='holder'>
    A :<input type='text' id='field1'/>
    B: <input type='text' id='field1'/>
  </div>

  #holder {border: solid 1px red; width: 400px; background-color: white;}
  input {border: none;}
  input:focus{outline:none;}
```

Comment: hey increase `#holder` width ;)

Comment: You should also have `input:focus{outline:none;}` in there too

Comment: @Griffin for only webkit browsers but yeah.

Answer (score 4):

It's css .. there is no way to marry 2 distinct `<input>` into one.

What you saw on the image is a styled `<div>` containing 2 `<input>` witch are 'styleless'

Answer (score 0):

test this
table with 4 columns set grouping to rows 
and inside  insert 2 text box with display style set to none in javascript in any event also with 2 label 
and another table with the submit button